# Find certain special characters using regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to find out if the input fields contains certain special characters such as <(@#$%^&*>. If user input has any of those characters,it should return true.

Example :Robert# ,S%am

```
public static boolean isInvalidCharacters(String input) throws Exception {
    try {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^<(@#$%^&*>]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        boolean isFound =matcher.find();
        if (!isFound) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        throw err;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is correct in essence, but it needs to be completed so that it marks not one character, but a string.

Try this regex

```
^[^<(@#$%^&*>]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RjEUio/1)

Java example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "abcd\nabcd@";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^<(@#$%^&*>]+$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    boolean isFound = matcher.find();

    System.out.println(!isFound);
}
```

Also there is a simple solution without regex

```
boolean isFound = "<(@#$%^&*>"
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf((char) x))
        .anyMatch(input::contains);
```

Comment: The questioner asked “if the input fields contains certain special characters” which obviously can be checked straight-forwardly, instead of checking whether the entire string consists of the negation of the special characters. Besides that, if you want to match the entire string, you can simply replace `find()` with `matches()` instead of adding `^` and `$` to the regex. Whether the “simple solution” is simpler, is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

In your code problem was leading `^` character. You can simplify it furthermore like this,

```
public static boolean isInvalidCharacters(String input) throws Exception {
    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[<()@#$%^&*>]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        return matcher.find();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

*Note: Logic is invalid if you return `true` when `isFound = false`.*

#### Edit

You can simplify further since `try-catch` block is not necessary.

```
public static boolean isInvalidCharacters(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[<()@#$%^&*>]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Also you can find more info regarding regex [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)